# Linq subqueries in same list / table

Tags: mysql, linq

First of all.. sorry for my English :)

I have a Mysql table with the following columns

```
ID | Column A | Column B
---+----------+----------
1    XYZ        123
1    ABC        234
2    KLM        987
2    XYZ        741
```

I want to find the ID where:

```
XYZ == 123 AND ABC == 234
```

For me to test I wrote a query in mysql that looks like that:

```
select distinct archivid
from archiv_values
where archivid in (select archivid
                   from archiv_values 
                   where (Column_A = 'XYZ' and VALUE = '123'))
  and archivid in (select archivid
                   from archiv_values 
                   where (Column_B = 'ABC' and VALUE = '234'))
```

This query works fine.

In my UI (WPF), I have a list of textboxes (in a listbox) where the user can make the search inputs.

The amount of searchable values is differently. Because of that I use foreach to run through the list of values:

```
Expression<Func<ArchivValue, bool>> searchCondition = m => true;

foreach (DocumentColumn col in lb_Filter.Items)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(col.InputValue))
    {
           searchCondition = searchCondition.And(m => m.Column_A == col.Column_A && m.Value == col.InputValue);
    }
}
```

This turns into a result that if I enter only one value, for example `123`, I find ID 1.

If I enter `123` and `234`, I find 0 items.

This is logical to me, but I can't find a way to do that with linq :-/

Comment: Can you show the query that uses the `searchCondition` expression?

Comment: `XYZ == 123` etc. XYZ never equals 123. What do you mean? `VALUE = '123'`. What is `VALUE`? I think I understand where you're heading, but you must more clearly state the problem.